# How to get text from table in rendered PHP with jquery in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been having trouble retrieving the text from within a page. I think it's because jquery is trying to retrieve data from the php file it's self instead of the rendered html.

When I try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert($("div#accountManager").html());
});
```

All I get is `<br>`

What I'm trying to do is get elements from within a specific tag.

Actually it goes like this:

```
<center>
   <div id="accountManager">
      <table class="optionsTable">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="optionsTable">
               <td class="optionsTable">
                  <!--<select disabled><option>Main account group</option></select><span style="float: right">This group's last run time: <b>N/A</b></span>-->
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="optionsTable">
               <td class="optionsTable">
                  <table id="accountsTable">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="globalCheckmark" checked="" onclick="onGlobalCheckmarkChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-lg"></i></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><i class="fa fa-flag fa-lg"></i></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><b>Usernames</b></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><b>Credits</b></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><b>Options</b></center>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="check1" checked="" onclick="onAccountCheckmarksChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status1"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_ms1"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_dt1"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><span id="accountName1" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">emali1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="credits1" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">378</span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="#" onclick="launchDashboardForAccount(1);return false;">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="launchEmailForAccount(1);return false;">Outlook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeAccount(1);return false;">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="check2" checked="" onclick="onAccountCheckmarksChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status2"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_ms2"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_dt2"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><span id="accountName2" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">emali2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="credits2" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">412</span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="#" onclick="launchDashboardForAccount(2);return false;">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="launchEmailForAccount(2);return false;">Outlook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeAccount(2);return false;">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="check3" checked="" onclick="onAccountCheckmarksChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status3"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_ms3"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_dt3"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><span id="accountName3" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">email3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="credits3" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">115</span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="#" onclick="launchDashboardForAccount(3);return false;">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="launchEmailForAccount(3);return false;">Outlook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeAccount(3);return false;">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <form name="add"><input type="radio" id="manager1" name="add1" onclick="changeAddAccountSection()" checked="">Add one account&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="manager2" name="add1" onclick="changeAddAccountSection()">Add accounts in bulk&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="manager3" name="add1" onclick="changeAddAccountSection()">Export accounts</form>
      <span id="accountAdder"><b>Add an account:</b><br>E-mail:<input placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Microsoft Live" id="username" size="30"><br>Password:<input type="password" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Password" id="password" size="25"><br><input type="button" id="addAccountButton" value="Add account" onclick="addAccountInManager()"></span><br><br><br><br><br>
   </div>
</center>
```

Above is a snippet of the html I'm trying to get the data from. Sorry I should have included the html structure before posting. I was afraid it was too long.

I've tried pretty much everything but I end up getting the raw php script for the page it's self.

Comment: just for try .. while id must be unique  you can use alert($("#accountManager").html()); wihtout div

Comment: Doing that just returns null.

Comment: That isn't all of the html, correct?

Comment: you forgot to close </div>

Comment: Woops. Forgot to include the raw html.

Comment: Alright. I fixed it. Sorry I should have done this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I got it. It turns out that I was looking for elements that were not yet loaded. I solved this by adding a one second timeout and it worked.

```
setTimeout(function() {
alert($("div#accountManager").html());
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to get inner html of specific element. Hence you should use innerHTMl as below. As well as your HTML is not properly structured.

```
alert($("#accountManager")[0].innerHTML);
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 alert($("#accountManager")[0].innerHTML); 
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
   <div id="accountManager">
      <table class="optionsTable">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="optionsTable">
               <td class="optionsTable">
                  <!--<select disabled><option>Main account group</option></select><span style="float: right">This group's last run time: <b>N/A</b></span>-->
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="optionsTable">
               <td class="optionsTable">
                  <table id="accountsTable">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="globalCheckmark" checked="" onclick="onGlobalCheckmarkChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-lg"></i></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><i class="fa fa-flag fa-lg"></i></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><b>Usernames</b></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><b>Credits</b></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><b>Options</b></center>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="check1" checked="" onclick="onAccountCheckmarksChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status1"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_ms1"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_dt1"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><span id="accountName1" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">emali1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="credits1" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">378</span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="#" onclick="launchDashboardForAccount(1);return false;">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="launchEmailForAccount(1);return false;">Outlook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeAccount(1);return false;">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="check2" checked="" onclick="onAccountCheckmarksChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status2"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_ms2"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_dt2"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><span id="accountName2" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">emali2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="credits2" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">412</span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="#" onclick="launchDashboardForAccount(2);return false;">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="launchEmailForAccount(2);return false;">Outlook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeAccount(2);return false;">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <center><input type="checkbox" id="check3" checked="" onclick="onAccountCheckmarksChange();"></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status3"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_ms3"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="status_dt3"><img src="../blue10.png" width="10" height="10"></span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><span id="accountName3" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">email3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                           <td>
                              <center><span id="credits3" style="color: rgb(250, 250, 250);">115</span></center>
                           </td>
                           <td><a href="#" onclick="launchDashboardForAccount(3);return false;">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="launchEmailForAccount(3);return false;">Outlook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeAccount(3);return false;">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br><br>
      <form name="add"><input type="radio" id="manager1" name="add1" onclick="changeAddAccountSection()" checked="">Add one account&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="manager2" name="add1" onclick="changeAddAccountSection()">Add accounts in bulk&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" id="manager3" name="add1" onclick="changeAddAccountSection()">Export accounts</form>
      <span id="accountAdder"><b>Add an account:</b><br>E-mail:<input placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Microsoft Live" id="username" size="30"><br>Password:<input type="password" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Password" id="password" size="25"><br><input type="button" id="addAccountButton" value="Add account" onclick="addAccountInManager()"></span><br><br><br><br><br>
   </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Nope. Still getting `<br>`

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I know this should work. I've tried it out in Jsfiddle and it worked perfectly too. I don't understand how this isn't working.